# Outer product of a vector with itself

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a special name for an outer product of a vector with itself? Is it a special case of a Gramian? I've seen them a thousand times, but I have no idea if such product has a name.

**Update**:
The case of outer product I'm talking about is $\vec{u}\vec{u}^T$ where $\vec{u}$ is a column vector.

Does is have a name in the form of *something* of $\vec{u}$?

Cheers!

Comment: The outer product of any vector with itself is always 0, since the outer product is skew symmetric. (EDIT: I would have made this a comment, but I don't have enough rep to do so on this stack exchange site ).

Comment: @Mikola: there are two things that get called the "outer product," and that's only one of them: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product . @Phonon: what definition of outer product are you working with? The coordinate one?

Comment: I updated my response. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In statistics, we call it the "sample autocorrelation matrix", which is like an estimation of [autocorrelation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_matrix) based on observed samples.

Comment: I guess this is the closes to what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The result is a particular case of a [dyadic tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_tensor). Is that what you are looking for?